# Why is .tex file on Mac OS X a package?

Tags: mac, texshop

After reloading my new computer, I discovered that TeXShop wouldn't open several .tex files. I further discovered that those files were in fact OS X packages. When I looked at the contents, there were files with the same filename as the package, but with extensions like .aux, .log, .pdf (typesetting), .tex (a true TeX file), .gz, and .png

Any idea what program created such a file? The only thing I had loaded on my old computer was MacTeX, but I don't think TeXShop creates such files does it?

I have other .tex files that are indeed text files.

Comment: Are you sure you did not inadvertently create directories with `.tex` extensions? Do the directories include another `.tex` in each case? Mac OS X packages are just directories, after all. They aren't some special kind of entity. Finder is just trained to display these directories (misleadingly) as if they were single things.

Comment: @cfr The answer can't be as simple as that, since e.g. if you do `mkdir foo.tex` the result just appears as a regular folder, not as a package.

Comment: Try rebuilding the Launch Services Database: in the terminal type
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` and then `killall Finder`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree it wouldn't explain its appearing as a package, but something has to have created the directory in order for there to be something to appear as a package, if you see what I mean. So 2 things have to go astray, I would think.

Comment: I shouldn't have said 'just' @AlanMunn ....

Comment: I'm sure I didn't inadvertently create directories, but some program could have done it. I don't recall having any TeX editors other than what came with MacTeX (TeXShop).